# Wordpress Get value of queried category in URL

Tags: wordpress

is it possible to know what's the first category queried in a wordpress URL?

Example:

http://www.mywebsite.com/category/mycat/mysubcat/

My Categories hierarchy is Something Like

```
Parent Cat 1
Parent Cat 2
Parent Cat 3
  Subcat 1
  Subcat 2
  Subcat 3
Parent Cat 4
  Subcat 1
  Subcat 2
  Subcat 3
```

What i'm trying to do is to echo the "mycat" value in archive.php, to do a conditional similar to:

if($value =="mycat") {
  ...
}
else { ... }

Why it's a little bit complicated? because each post belongs to **at least 1 sub-cat from each parent** plus 1 of the parent category with no childs.

I need something similar to $cat = get_query_var('cat'); (in this case $cat returns mysubcat)

Any Ideas?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can try using get_category_by_path() it'll give you the first category given a URL.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_path

Answer (score 0):

Test with this simple function of WP:

```
<?php $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat')); ?>
```

taken from the official directory of wordpress:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$elms = explode('/', $uri) ;
$firstcat = $elms[2] ;

if($firstcat == "products") {

// We show products grid

}

elseif($firstcat == "accesories") {

// We Show accesories grid

}

else {

// Whatever!

}
```

Comment: using `explode()` and getting the 3rd array value isn't reliable especially when the install could be in a sub-directory like `http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/category/mycat/mysubcat/` or `http://www.mywebsite.com/eu/blog/category/mycat/mysubcat/`